# How to make a case-insensitive unique column in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, pdo

I haven't been able to find the answer to this. I'm trying to create a table with a unique email address column. And when I do

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  email TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  password TEXT NOT NULL CHECK(password<>''),
  UNIQUE (lower(email))
)
```

when using PDO, I get the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "(": syntax error' in script.php:65 Stack trace: #0 script.php(65): PDO->exec('CREATE TABLE us...') #1 {main} thrown in script.php on line 65

Line 65 is the `CREATE TABLE` line.  If I take out the `UNIQUE`, it works fine. Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`COLLATE NOCASE`](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation) is your friend:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  email TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  password TEXT NOT NULL CHECK(password<>''),
  UNIQUE (email COLLATE NOCASE)
)
```

Comment: Sorry, if you find it irrelevant but having made a column like that unique, how to catch the case when user enters existing data and display a toast?

Answer (score 3):

For speed, make all your input lower case first, and use a normal unique column.

This is great for read-more-frequent-than-write use cases because queries just need to compare strings, rather than converting the field first which it must do lots of times to compare.

Comment: It is better to do the enforcement within the database rather than in the clients performing the input, as you can't always decide where the data is coming from, like when you are importing the data from an external source.

Comment: Alec Teal, you claim this is for speed, but have you benchmarked this?  I did.  Case A stored the original text and a separate derived field with lowercased text (unique constraint on lowercased field).  Case B stored just the original and used unique constraint with COLLATE NOCASE.  For case A, inserts were about 5-8% slower (more data) and searches were 15-20% slower than case B, and sorting was about even.

Comment: "searches were 15-20% slower than case B" did you add COLLATE NOCASE to the where condition as well?

Comment: @DanieleRicci 85% of statistics are made up.