# Case insensitive unique column in sqlite with ORMLite

Tags: java, ormlite

My requirements are very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914946/how-to-make-a-case-insensitive-unique-column-in-sqlite) on SO. the solution is also straight forward COLLATE NOCASE. I just need to know how to implement this with ORMLite.

Haven't been able to find the right annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After  a bit more RTFM, columnDefinition looks to be the right annotation.