# How to add a unique insensitive constraint on a peewee model?

Tags: sqlite, peewee

I would like to add a unique insensitive constraint to the following model using peewee orm with a sqlite database

```
import peewee as p

db = p.SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

class Player(p.Model):
   name = p.CharField()
  
   class Meta:
      database = db
```

I would like to prevent adding 'joe' and 'Joe' as player name in the table. As the field is case sensitive, a unique constraint is not enough.

Thank you for your ideas !

Comment: You can for this post about same problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914946/how-to-make-a-case-insensitive-unique-column-in-sqlite

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't know about collate. I will look into it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify arbitrary constraints in the Meta.constraints list:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

class K(Model):
    key = TextField()
    class Meta:
        constraints = [SQL('UNIQUE ("key" COLLATE NOCASE)')]
        database = db

db.create_tables([K])

K.create(key='k1')
K.create(key='K1') # Fails
```

Comment: This code is working as I expect. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

For reference, syntax for creating a case insensitive unique constraint on two fields would be:

```
class Group(BaseModel):
    name = CharField()
    category = CharField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [SQL('UNIQUE("name" COLLATE NOCASE, "category" COLLATE NOCASE)')]
```