# Case insensitive unique column when using gorm with sqlite driver

Tags: go, go-gorm

In my Golang application, I am using a Name column in one of my structs.
I want to save the text in its original form, so for example "User1", but "user1" would be considered to be duplicate. Is this possible with gorm and sqlite driver?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a case-insensitive unique column in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914946/how-to-make-a-case-insensitive-unique-column-in-sqlite)

Comment: This isn't really a matter of your Go libraries but of your MySQL collation. Configure your table in a manner that the `name` column has a case insensitive collation, e.g. `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` (the "`_ci`" suffix tells that it's case insensitive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually overriding the column's datatype to 'text collate nocase' worked for me, like so:

```
type User struct {
    ID   int
    Name string `gorm:"index:,unique;type:text collate nocase"`
}
```